# Google App Engine datastore - Enums

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, enums, google-cloud-datastore

Im trying to save and query an enum into a Google App Engine datastore using JPA.
According to [DataNucleas](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_2_2/jpa/types.html) an Enum is a JPA persistable data type by default. But what im getting is the following exception :

```
com.xxx.utils.ActionLogUtils logCreateUserAction: actiontype: **com.xxx.endpoints.ActionLog$ACTION_TYPE** is not a supported property type.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: actiontype: **com.xxx.endpoints.ActionLog$ACTION_TYPE** is not a supported property type.
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedSingleValue(DataTypeUtils.java:235)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:207)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:173)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:148)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PropertyContainer.setProperty(PropertyContainer.java:101)
```

my entity class looks like this :

```
@Entity
public class ActionLog {

public static enum ACTION_TYPE {
    ACTION_1(1),
    ACTION_2(2),
    ACTION_3(3);

    private final int value;
    private ACTION_TYPE(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}


private ACTION_TYPE actiontype;

public ActionLog() {

}

public ACTION_TYPE getActiontype() {
    return actiontype;
}

public void setActiontype(ACTION_TYPE actiontype) {
    this.actiontype = actiontype;
}
}
```

And the code that causes the exception is :

```
public static void logCreateUserAction(String userId) {
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

    try {
        Key userKey = KeyFactory.createKey("User", userId);
        Entity actionLogEntity = new Entity("ActionLog", userKey);  
        actionLogEntity.setProperty("actiontype", ACTION_TYPE.ACTION_1);
        datastore.put(actionLogEntity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong here ? I really searched the web and google's documenation but couldn't find anything about enums. Can you please help ? Im really stucked here.

Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it.

Comment: There's a public test that shows use of enums in JPA with GAE, all works. Suggest you debug your code and see what you're doing different. https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/trunk/tests/com/google/appengine/datanucleus/jpa/JPAEnumTest.java

Comment: @DataNucleus Thanks for your reply. Is there a way to persist enums with low level APIs (or maybe simulate the way JPA does it) ? The method i wrote above can be called also from servlets, where i dont have access to EntityManager instance.

Comment: You don't say what version of Google's JPA plugin you're using, and why you're referring to v2.2 of DataNucleus docs I've no idea (no version of Google's plugin works with that). You omit the rest of the stack trace which would have provided useful info about where this comes from. Also look at the log

Comment: @DataNucleus Im using JPA plugin v2. The rest of the stack trace is irrelevant to the problem at it describes my application code. Im adding 2 lines to the method above which i forgot to put and hopefully will clarify things a bit (Entity extends PropertyContainer, which is the last line in the stack trace). From the sound of you, i understand this is a common operation that suppose to work with enums ? persisting an enum property through low level API ?

Comment: @DataNucleus care to share your thoughts on this ?

Comment: @DataNucleus the link provided doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed this in my own code. You are trying to save the value as an Enum but you should save the String "name" of the enum. Try using `actionLogEntity.setProperty("actiontype", ACTION_TYPE.ACTION_1.name());`